# Can Firebase be used in an app supported by another Backend and Database?

Tags: firebase, chat

I am looking to make an app that would have its Backend on another service like AWS or some other. This app would be having many features and functionalities.
But for chat feature, I am exploring options and wondering that would I be able to integrate Firebase in my app.

I have read about Firebase Functions to add more functionality at the backend and also the installation of Firebase Admin to servers.
But still I am not convinced about their capabilities and exactly what all I can do with them.

It would be great if someone who has experience with Firebase help me out figuring if going with it is the best case for me or is there something else I should look into.

Answer (score 0):

So first you can't use Firebase in combination with AWS or Azure etc. Firebase is based on Google Cloud and is the interface between the mobile client (the running app on the client's smartphone) and the backend (your Firebase project).

What I use is, for example, Firebase Cloud Messaging, to simply notify one or multiple users by trigger an HTTP Request from my own web server.

I also made some apps to store the data in FireStore or in the Realtime-Database, so that I don't have to set up a whole new infrastructure. And this is basically the goal of Firebase that you can simply start with your app, without carrying about that.

So what I've heard about Firebase is that you currently cannot install Firebase on a server of your choice and you have to use Google Cloud.

Hopefully, you can do something with my answer. If you have further questions feel free to ask them.

Comment: ok, so in your opinion if I have to make an app with broader scope and add chat feature then I should look for other options, instead of FCM?

Comment: @Dip Depends on what you mean with broader scope. You can create nearly everything with it, once you learnt how to use it and how to use NoSQL Databases. But keep in mind that all data which you store on Firebase is located maybe on servers in the U.S which can be for some enterprises be a problem. As well, when Firebase is going to shut down their system in the future, then you may have to rebuild the app if they wouldn't publish the source code. But that I think wouldn't happen in the next 10 years because Google is there one of the market leaders.